# How add values from multiple radio input

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have 2 forms and I would like to get the addition of values of these 2 forms.
Example: in q1 I select 2 and in q2 I select 4, in my class result I want to display 6.
The solution should be work with 30 forms too :)

**HTML**

```
<div class="q1">
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"> 1                       
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2"> 2                       
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3"> 3
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="4"> 4
  </form>
</div>

<div class="q2">
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1"> 1                       
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2"> 2                       
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3"> 3
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="4"> 4
  </form>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

**jQuery**

I get the values but I can't add them.

```
$('.q1').on('click',function(){
    var r1 = $('input[name=q1]:checked').val();
    $('.result').html(r1);
});

$('.q2').on('click',function(){
    var r2 = $('input[name=q2]:checked').val();     
    $('.result').html(r2);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2cghnw7/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a generic className to the `.q1` and `.q2` wrapper elements and then:

```
var $inputs = $('.question input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
    var total = 0;
    $inputs.filter(':checked').each(function() {
        total += +this.value;
    });

    $('.result').text(total);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2fjnxcd/

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest:

```
// binding a change-event handler to inputs of type radio:
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    // setting the text of .result:
    $('.result').text(function(){
        // iterating over the checked radios whose name begins with 'q':
        return $('input[type="radio"][name^="q"]:checked').map(
            function(){
                // returning the value of the current input, as a number:
                return +(this.value || 0);
            // converting the map into an array, and reducing the array into:
            }).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
            // the sum of the numbers of the array:
            return a + b;
        });
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j2cghnw7/3/).

References:

- Array:

  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var r1=0, r2=0; 
$('.q1').on('click',function(){
    r1 = parseInt($('input[name=q1]:checked').val());
    $('.result').html( r1 + r2);
});

$('.q2').on('click',function(){
    r2 = parseInt($('input[name=q2]:checked').val());   
    $('.result').html( r1 + r2);
});
```

Comment: Make sure you pass in the radix param for the `parseInt` method. It defaults to base 10, but it's still safer.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it safer if it uses 10 as default?

Comment: MDN suggests always passing in the radix. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt